# Surroundings to see where a car is going (drawing projective)

Tags: geometry, transformation, projective-geometry, computer-vision

I want to solve one task to determine the surroundings on the road to see where a car is going (using camera).

**Input data**

I use Android smartphone and its camera. Android also can give many useful information (values) from its sensors

[Input data (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfcKP.png)

- height of camera, mm
- width of car (vehicle), mm
- roll camera, degrees
- pitch camera, degrees
- horizontal/vertical angle of view (camera's field of view), degrees

**Output data** - the result I want to get (lines on the sides)

[Result - Output data (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK4Uz.png)

So I want to understand how to calculate points to draw such lines on the frames (photos) made by camera

Is there any known formulas for such tasks?

Comment: Is this the right stage?

Comment: Note that the angle view of the camera strictly speaking isn't enough information to go on, because different lenses can pack those degrees differently. I don't think the differences are _that_ large between phone cameras, but I feel it should be pointed out.

Comment: @Arthur I can also get information about sizes of sensor (width/height) in mm from Android